# Releasing an artifact in staging repository

Tags: maven, release, staging, sonatype

I've deployed a maven artifact to ossrh. It is now in a staging repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central_bundles-7996)

How can I release this artifact ? Trying via `mvn nexus-staging:release` or from webapp on oss.sonatype.org, I get a 403 : unauthorized...

Answer (score 2):

I must create a issue of type "New Project" in http://issues.sonatype.org/

Then when the project wil be created, confirm on the issue that everything is correct, and that the artifact can be released.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually go to the oss nexus and release it.

[Close and Drop or Release Your Staging Repository](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/releasing-the-deployment.html#close-and-drop-or-release-your-staging-repository)

> Once you have successfully closed the staging repository, you can release it by pressing the Release button. This will move the components into the release repository of OSSRH where it will be synced to the Central Repository.

Comment: The staging repository has been automatically clean.

But in the documentation you pointed, there is this :

`If you are releasing the first time, do not forget to comment on the issue tracker ticket, letting us know that you have completed a release so we can activate your sync process`

I've never filled a JIRA ticket before... what does this means ?

Comment: I did, the first time I released something. Then I released only with nexus.

Comment: You must create a JIRA ticket on [Jira](http://issue.sonatype.org). **Be carefull**, create a "New Project" ticket, **only for each root groupId** you own. For example, I own marchand.top, I've created a ticket for top.marchand groupId and not for sub-groupIds, like top.marchand.xml